# How to type chinese on scandinavian keyboard layout?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout, language

I use a norwegian keyboard, and I am currently learning chinese. So I want to type with ms pinyin. I have set my pc up so that it is in english but still recognizing my norwegian layout. Which is very easy, I just selected the norwegian keyboard layout. But the chinese language package does not have the same options under keyboards, there is only ms pinyin and ms wubi! How can I type chinese on my norwegian keyboard? I use windows 10.

Comment: A possible workaround is using [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). I'm not sure how Norwegian keyboard works, but you would be able to find some AHK script which convert a US English QWERTY keyboard to Norwegian keyboard. which should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a very elegant solution to use Chinese input with non-QWERTY keyboards. 
First of all you need hit Windows Start button and enter: `regedit`, then press ENTER and confirm with Admin rights.

For Windows 10:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts\00000804`

[image: Registry Editor, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts\00000804]

In "Layout File" change from KBDUS.DLL to **KBDNO.DLL**

All keyboard layouts can be found from http://kbdlayout.info/

Then save the registry file and **restart** your PC. Voila and have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Using the Chinese Simplified language and the Microsoft Pinyin keyboard,
you choose this language in the language bar and then type Chinese letter
names using Latin names, then choose among the displayed candidate characters.

Example:

[image]

More information:

- [Pinyin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinyin)
  A romanization system for Standard Chinese in mainland China and to some extent in Taiwan.
- [Pinyin input method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinyin_input_method)

Comment: This does not answer my question. I am able to type the all the roman characters but "everything else" is in the wrong place because of the differnce in layouts between the scandinavian keyboard and american that comes with ms pinyin keyboard.

Comment: This clarifies the problem. I think the solution would be to change the language to Chinese and then use the On-Screen Keyboard (OSK) or the Touch Keyboard to type using the mouse, rather than using the physical keyboard.

Comment: That would just be ignoring the problem. If you think it is not possible to change the input layout of ms pinyin, please provide an answer where you think why it would be the case.

Comment: There are no resources I could find, and none of the options of the Microsoft Pinyin keyboard (there are many) address this problem. So I think that your own experience should be taken into account.